# Angular 5 - Angular firebase - Testing - mocking getDownloadURL method

Tags: angular, unit-testing, firebase, testing, karma-jasmine

I have difficulities in mocking the getDownLoadURL method the console everytime shows: 
**TownhallPictureService should be return townhall level by valid input FAILED TypeError: this.ref.getDownloadURL is not a function**

my Service looks like:

```
@Injectable()
export class TownhallPictureService {

  public ref;

  constructor(private storage: AngularFireStorage) {
  }

  getTownHallPicture(townhall: number): Observable<string | null> {
    switch (townhall) {
      case 1:
        this.ref = this.storage.ref(TownhallImgSrc.TOWNHALL_ONE);
        break;
        ...
        break;
      case 11:
        this.ref = this.storage.ref(TownhallImgSrc.TOWNHALL_ELEVEN);
        break;
      default:
        return Observable.of(undefined);
    }
    return this.ref.getDownloadURL();
  }
}
```

And the jasmine spec file:

```
    describe('TownhallPictureService', () => {
  let spy;
  const angularFireMock = {
    ref(){
      function getDownloadURL() {}
    },
  };
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [TownhallPictureService,
        {provide: AngularFireStorage, useValue: angularFireMock},
        ]
    });
    spy = TestBed.get(AngularFireStorage);
  });

  it('should be return townhall level by valid input', inject(
    [TownhallPictureService], (service: TownhallPictureService) => {
      const expectedTownhall: number = 9;
      const expectedPicture: string = TownhallImgSrc.TOWNHALL_NINE;

      spyOn(spy, 'ref').and.returnValue(Observable.of(TownhallImgSrc.TOWNHALL_NINE));

      service.getTownHallPicture(expectedTownhall).subscribe(result => {
        expect(result).toBe(expectedPicture);
      });
    }));
```

Does anyone know how to mock properly this method? The problem here is : getDownloadURL is a method from a different class, so i need some kind of a nested mock obj.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the people who use **AngularFirebaseStorage** and want to build unit tests around this Service thats the way to mock ref() and getDownloadURL():
Create a FakeClass:

```
export class FirebaseMock {

  public ref(path: string) {
      return {
        getDownloadURL() {
          return Observable.of(path)
        }
      }
  }
}
```

And inject it into the real into the class' constructor that needs to be tested:

```
let mock: any;
  let service: TownhallPictureService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    mock = new FirebaseMock();
    service = new TownhallPictureService(mock);
  });
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this same answer, but with TestBed.inject ?